# AngularJS: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx

My angularjs example app is running fine in my netbeans ide based local server. But when I moved the application to nginx server it gives me the following error in the browser.

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: views/login.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/tpload?p0=views%2Flogin.html
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at handleError (angular.js:16133)
    at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
    at angular.js:13264
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at done (angular.js:9698)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9888)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9829)
```

**My app.js**

```
appModule
        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'loginController',
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
                })
                .when('/main',
                {
                    controller: 'dashboardController',
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }])
```

Comment: Get sure that the folder 'views' is at the same level as your config file from the main-module.

Comment: Try to go to `domain/views/login.html`. If you can't go there, neither can angular.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, and I CAN go there manually... Then I push the back button, and the page and partial template are loaded... but if I try to click my routing menu button, it once again fails.  E.G.: It only works when I manually go to the page, then push "back" to the templated page.  O.O?

Comment: @Suamere The template load issue persisted just because of wrong folder structure. Make sure you got views and config at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

I came to find out that my issue was regarding Default $http Headers.  I had just recently added a default header for `Authorization`, and a default `Accept` for `application/json`.

**SURPRISE!!!**  It turns out that those $http headers are NOT only applied to $http calls  you make to your endpoints... but also to every call made that pulls your **Routing** html files.  And since html files will explode if using those headers, the whole thing fails.

I simply stopped setting the Default $http headers, and wrote a side service that my microservice calls would use since they need app/json.  Then my Angular Routing calls went back to using standard headers.

Comment: How did you avoid the headers from .html files?

Comment: @michaelvidal Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use node.js, try this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'yourFolder/invoices')));
```

Comment: please try to be more specific